# Spell checker not checking for capital letters

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

Following is my code for ASPX page:

```
<td colspan="2">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessageBody" runat="server" Rows="8" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="1180px"
        CssClass="Label" />
    <igspc:WebSpellChecker ID="wscSpellCheck" runat="server"  TextComponentId="txtMessageBody" ButtonId="btnCcheck">
        <DialogOptions ShowNoErrorsMessage="true"  />
    </igspc:WebSpellChecker>
    <div runat="server" id="divSpecllCheck">                                 
        <input type="button" id="btnCcheck"  value="Spell Check" />
    </div>                                       
</td>
```

I am not able to check the spelling of the all the upper case letters ..In other wise If i enter CTA for CAT its saying there are no matching words found for it

Answer (score 0):

Set SpellOptions.PerformanceOptions.AllowCapitalizedWords to False.  The updated markup for the WebSpellChecker:

```
<ig_spell:WebSpellChecker ID="wscSpellCheck" runat="server" TextComponentId="txtMessageBody" ButtonId="btnCcheck">
    <SpellOptions>
        <PerformanceOptions AllowCapitalizedWords="False"/>
    </SpellOptions>
    <DialogOptions ShowNoErrorsMessage="true" />
</ig_spell:WebSpellChecker>
```

For more details see the [PerformanceOptions Class Members](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.WebUI.WebSpellChecker.v12.2~Infragistics.WebUI.WebSpellChecker.PerformanceOptions_members.html) in the NetAdvantage API documentation.